# trying to SUM a MAX value from a database

Tags: mysql

im getting  Undefined index: total any idea what im doing wrong

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(max_score) FROM (SELECT war_enemy, MAX(score) AS max_score FROM score WHERE war_enemy ='$enemy_name' GROUP BY enemy_enemynumber) AS total";
$result = mysqli_query($database,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($database));
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){      
echo $res['SUM(max_score)'];
echo $res['total'];
}
```

i try removing the AS total and getting the Every derived table must have its own alias
any ideas whats wrong

Comment: What is this line supposed to be doing?  `echo $res['total'];`?  Your query is not returning anything called `total`.

Comment: include enemy_enemynumber in your select

Comment: sorry i guess i didnt delete that line before posting here

Comment: this is the error, trying to access not existing index `echo $res['total'];`

Comment: thats correct i been coding for hours i guess i didnt see that